# Bug in ARCore acquireDepthImage?

Tags: arcore

The documentation states that it's 16 bits each with top 3 bits set to 0, meaning the range should be about 8,192. My code is calling

`depthImage.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer().asShortBuffer().get(x)`

The range of these numbers is about the full signed short range and seemingly random. To debug, I tried printing the following values:

```
depthImage.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer().get(0);
depthImage.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer().get(1);
```

The first one oscillates randomly and the second one is almost always in the low numbers such as 0-6, but I've seen as high as 21.

It seems like the 2nd byte is the most significant byte of the number and the 1st byte is the least significant byte (i.e. they are reversed).

Comment: Did you find anything regarding this matter?

Comment: It had something to do with little endian or big endian settings

Answer (score 0):

It's little-endian encoding, use Short.reverseBytes():

```
depthMm = java.lang.Short.reverseBytes(depthImage.planes[0].buffer.getShort(offset))
```